# Passing an ObservableCollection as a parameter in a method to another class

Tags: c#, wpf, object, observablecollection

I would like to pass a ObservableCollection as a parameter in a method to another method in another class. The method call from the source class looks like this `saveLoadSerialization.Save(ClassDatas,Connectors, fileName);`. `ClassDatas` and `Connectors` is both an object. These objects is defined like this in the source class:

`public ObservableCollection<ClassData> ClassDatas { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Connector> Connectors { get; set; }`

The target class where the Save-method exists looks like this:

```
public void Save(IList _classDatas, IList _connectors, String fileName)
{
    // ClassData Object
    try
    {
       XmlSerializer xsClassData = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<ClassData>)); <--- fails here
       if (_classDatas.Count > 0)
       {
          using (StreamWriter swClassData = new StreamWriter(fileName))
          {
              xsClassData.Serialize(swClassData, _classDatas);
          }
       }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
     }

     // Connector Object
     try
     {
        XmlSerializer xsConnector = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Connector>)); <-- fails here
        if (_connectors.Count > 0)
        {
            using (StreamWriter swConnector = new StreamWriter(fileName))
            {
                xsConnector.Serialize(swConnector, _connectors);
            }
        }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
     }
}
```

If I change the line `XmlSerializer xsConnector = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Connector>));` to `XmlSerializer xsConnector = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<_connectors>));` I receive the same error for both of them: "The type or namespace name '_connectors' could not be found".

I cannot see why it doesn't work?!

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: What problem? All I see is a list of requirements.

Comment: What's the error message when your code snippet compile? maybe `XmlSerializer` can't serialize `ObservableCollection`, how about `BinaryFormatter`?

Comment: @SimonChan 1>C:\Source\Repos\UMLDiagram\UMLDiagram\ViewModel\SaveLoadSerialization.cs(28,95,28,104): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ClassData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>C:\Source\Repos\UMLDiagram\UMLDiagram\ViewModel\SaveLoadSerialization.cs(45,95,45,104): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Connector' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The error message is clear: the types `ClassData` and `Connector` are not defined in any assembly the code you're trying to compile references. So, figure out what assembly they are defined in and add the reference to that assembly.